# Como fazer um select com colunas dinâmicas para cada like?

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo um select para um relatório de ligações por operadora e cada coluna de quantidade, eu tenho um select composto e que deve me retornar a quantidade de ligações de cada operadora.

```
SELECT date(calldate) as 'Data',
(select count(*) FROM cdr where dstchannel like '%claro%' and (calldate between '2014-08-01' and '2014-08-11' ) ) as 'Claro',
(select count(*) FROM cdr where dstchannel like '%tim%' and (calldate between '2014-08-01' and '2014-08-11' ) ) as 'Tim',
(select count(*) FROM cdr where dstchannel like '%vivo%' and (calldate between '2014-08-01' and '2014-08-11' ) ) as 'Vivo',
(select count(*) FROM cdr where dstchannel like '%oi%' and (calldate between '2014-08-01' and '2014-08-11' ) ) as 'Oi',
(select count(*) FROM cdr where dstchannel like '%nextel%' and(calldate between '2014-08-01' and '2014-08-11' ) ) as 'Nextel'
FROM cdr where
(dstchannel regexp 'claro|Tim|vivo|oi|nextel')
and (calldate between '2014-08-01' and '2014-08-11' ) group by date(calldate)
```

O Resultado que está retornado é o mesmo valor em cada linha com o total, sem separar por data.

Comment: Você tem outros valores possíveis em `dstchannel`?

Comment: Tenho sim. No caso, eu quero pegar somente os das 5 operadoras.
Se eu pegar cada subselect e fizer a consulta separadas, vai retornar o resultado correto.
Mas eu precisso que isso esteja no mesmo select sepadado apenas por coluna, entendeu?

Comment: Se cada operadora viesse numa linha diferente não te serve?

Comment: Seja como for, o problema é no seu GROUP BY.

Comment: Acho que não, porque cada coluna representa uma operadora.
Se eu tiver só a data e a quantidade, como que eu vou saber de quem é o que?
Imagino que seja no group by, mas não sei como faço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o sum(), por ex:

```
SELECT date( calldate ) AS 'Data', sum( dstchannel LIKE '%claro%' ) claro, sum( dstchannel LIKE '%oi%' ) oi
FROM cdr where
(dstchannel regexp 'claro|Tim|vivo|oi|nextel')
and (calldate between '2014-08-01' and '2014-08-11' ) group by date(calldate)
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Toda a tabela:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou @Jader.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Se você aceitar que cada operadora venha numa linha, e não numa coluna, pode simplesmente fazer assim:

```
SELECT 
    calldate AS Data,
    dstchannel AS Operadora,
    COUNT(*) AS Quantiade
FROM cdr 
WHERE dstchannel REGEXP 'claro|tim|vivo|oi|nextel'
    AND calldate BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-11' 
GROUP BY dstchannel, YEAR(calldate), MONTH(calldate), DAY(calldate)
ORDER BY dstchannel, YEAR(calldate), MONTH(calldate), DAY(calldate)
```

Comment: No mysql funcionaria substituir `REGEXP` por `IN ('claro', 'tim', 'vivo', 'oi', 'nextel')` ?

Comment: Sim, se o valor da coluna for exatamente um desses (porque regexp vai casar com "Operadora Claro" e coisas do tipo).

Comment: Eu tenho que ter coluna separa pq esse valores serão implementados num highcharts.
Eu não posso trabalhar com in pq o valor da operadora é tipo `'SIP/712_NEXTEL1-000000b3`'.
Por isso que eu uso like.
@bfavaretto
O seu select não agrupou.
Obrigado.